# What's the difference between std::vector and dynamic allocated array?

Tags: c++

I have wrote two functions to compare the time cost of std::vector and dynamic allocated array

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <chrono>

void A() {
  auto t1 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
  std::vector<float> data(5000000);
  auto t2 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();

  float *p = data.data();
  for (int i = 0; i < 5000000; ++i) {
    p[i] = 0.0f;
  }
  auto t3 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
  std::cout << std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>(t2 - t1).count() << " us\n";
  std::cout << std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>(t3 - t2).count() << " us\n";
}

void B() {
  auto t1 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
  auto* data = new float [5000000];
  auto t2 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
  float *ptr = data;
  for (int i = 0; i < 5000000; ++i) {
    ptr[i] = 0.0f;
  }
  auto t3 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
  std::cout << std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>(t2 - t1).count() << " us\n";
  std::cout << std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>(t3 - t2).count() << " us\n";
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
  A();
  B();
  return 0;
}
```

A() cost about 6000 us to initialize the vector, then 1400 us to fill zeros.

B() cost less than 10 us to allocate memory, then 5800 us to fill zeros.

Why their time costs have such a large difference?

compiler: g++=9.3.0

flags: -O3 -DNDEBUG

Comment: How do you benchmark? How many repeats? Which first? Do you even free the newed memory?

Comment: what compiler and which settings did you use to compile the code? Optimizations turned on? I doubt it, because most of the code has no observable effect and can be optimized away completely. When you care about performance, the very first measure should be to turn on compiler optimizations

Comment: Please show a [mre] including compiler, compiler version and compiler settings

Comment: Allocating memory through `new float [5000000]` takes only 10us most likely because nothing is actually being allocated, OS only makes a note that you want so much memory but only gives it to your process when you try to write to it which is why writing to it takes longer. Other then that try different optimization levels.

Comment: Benchmarking the shown code is pointless, it doesn't resemble any real-world use case. You fill the array/vector with zeros but you don't actually use it. So what you do is to test if the compiler can determine that you actually do nothing with `data` and if it is able to optimize certain parts or everything away. You should test your code with `clang 13` your `B` will be amazing _"fast"_ there and take `0 us` for initializing and setting the values to zero.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, note that the `std::vector<float>` constructor already zeros the vector.

There are many plausible system-level explanations for the behavior you observe:

One very plausible is caching: When you allocate the array using new, the memory referenced by the returned pointer is not in the cache. When you create a vector, the constructor will zero the allocated memory area under the hood thereby bringing the memory to the cache. Subsequent zeroing will hit in the cache thus.

Other reasons might include compiler optimizations. A compiler might realize that your zeroing is unneccesary with std::vector. Given the figures you obtained I would discount this here though.

Comment: Additional consideration is that a heap allocation itself may completely skip any use of the pages allocated in the virtual address space. It can only reserve them an once a page is accessed for the first time, page fault occurs and that page is then mapped to a physical memory.

Answer (score 4):

QuickBench is a nice tool to compare different ways doing the same thing.
https://quick-bench.com/q/p4ThYlVCa7VbO6vy6LEVVZ_0CVs

Your array example leaves a huge memory leak and QuickBench gives an error because of that.

The code I used (added two more variants):

```
static void Vector(benchmark::State& state) {
  // Code inside this loop is measured repeatedly
  for (auto _ : state) {
    std::vector<float> data(500000);
    float *p = data.data();
    for (int i = 0; i < 500000; ++i) {
      p[i] = 0.0f;
    }
    // Make sure the variable is not optimized away by compiler
    benchmark::DoNotOptimize(data);
  }
}
// Register the function as a benchmark
BENCHMARK(Vector);

static void VectorPushBack(benchmark::State& state) {
  for (auto _ : state) {
    std::vector<float> data;
    for (int i = 0; i < 500000; ++i) {
      data.push_back(0.0f);
    }
    benchmark::DoNotOptimize(data);
  }
}
BENCHMARK(VectorPushBack);

static void VectorInit(benchmark::State& state) {
  for (auto _ : state) {
    std::vector<float> data(500000, 0.0f);
    benchmark::DoNotOptimize(data);
  }
}
BENCHMARK(VectorInit);

static void Array(benchmark::State& state) {
  for (auto _ : state) {
    auto* data = new float [500000];
    float *ptr = data;
    for (int i = 0; i < 500000; ++i) {
      ptr[i] = 0.0f;
    }
    benchmark::DoNotOptimize(data);
    delete[] data;
  }
}
BENCHMARK(Array);

static void ArrayInit(benchmark::State& state) {
  for (auto _ : state) {
    auto* data = new float [500000]();
    benchmark::DoNotOptimize(data);
    delete[] data;
  }
}
BENCHMARK(ArrayInit);


static void ArrayMemoryLeak(benchmark::State& state) {
  for (auto _ : state) {
    auto* data = new float [500000];
    float *ptr = data;
    for (int i = 0; i < 500000; ++i) {
      ptr[i] = 0.0f;
    }
    benchmark::DoNotOptimize(data);
  }
}
//BENCHMARK(ArrayMemoryLeak);
```

Results:
[image: QuickBench results]

All variants but the `push_back` one are almost the same in runtime. But the vector is much safer. It's very easy to forget to free the memory (as you demonstrated yourself).

EDIT: Fixed the mistake in the `push_back` variant. Thanks to `t.niese` and `Scheff's Cat` for pointing it out and fixing it.

Comment: @scheffs-cat thanks, I edited my answer to include your fixed QuickBench

Comment: Benchmarking isn't an easy task, especially with such an arbitrary example. From the results, it is not clear if you either test how well you crafted the benchmark to be fair, or if some of the `benchmark::DoNotOptimize` prevented some optimizations at one test but still allowed it in other tests. You actually can't obtain much information from those results (except maybe `push_back` case).

Comment: A test that might be closer to what will happen with actual data might be this [quick-bench](https://quick-bench.com/q/b-pw4FV2Ay7urruNKn4tfZ-gm5g) but even from that one, I would not draw too many conclusions. No matter how you test that arbitrary code, you likely will never get results that will reflect what results you will get in an actual project.