# Difference between a vector and a dynamically allocated array

Tags: c++, collections, libraries

What are the internal differences of choosing to use an `std::vector` vs a dynamically allocated array? I mean, not only performance differences like in this [matching title question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71292753/whats-the-difference-between-stdvector-and-dynamic-allocated-array).

I mean, I try to design a library. So I want to offer a wrapper over an `StackArray`, that is just a `C-Style` array with some member methods that contains as a member `T array[N]`. No indirections and the `new` operator removed to force the implementor to have a array type always stored in the stack.

Now, I want to offer the dynamic variant. So, with a little effort, I just can declare something like:

```
template <typename T>
class DynArray
{
    T* array,
    size_t size,
    size_t capacity
};
```

But... this seems pretty similar to a base approach to a `C++ vector`.

Also, an array stored in the heap can be resized by copying the elements to a new mem location (is this true?). That's pretty much the same that makes a vector when a `push_back()` operation exceeds its allocated capacity, for example, right?

Should I offer both API's if exists some notable differences? Or I am overcomplicated the design of the library and may I just have my `StackArray` and the `Vector` should be just the safe abstraction over a dynamically allocated array?

Comment: You don't have to worry about explicit memory management when using `vector`. A very similar question was asked few days ago.

Comment: `StackArray` sounds awfully like `std::array`

Comment: @JasonLiam I mean, by the view point of the library designer, not the client code

Comment: `T* array[N]` is an array of pointers, held within the object. To use it you would have to store actual pointers into that array.

Comment: both of you are completly right. I should edit and update that code snippet in the question

Comment: Guess that now it's corrected?

Comment: Many years ago the were only fixed-size arrays, People wanting dynamic array had to code on their own, relocating memory and other matters. Then, 'vector' came into show, and people didn't need their own implementation any more.

Comment: @AlexVergara A `std::vector` does much more internally than naively using `new[]` and `delete[]`, while at the same time, adhering to the requirement of the data lie in contiguous memory.  In addition, the [std::stack](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/stack) is a container adapter that uses internally *any* type that has the requisite functions, `back()`, `push_back()` and `pop_back()`.  If your `DynArray` class has those functions, then `std::stack<T, DynArray<T>>` will work correctly, automatically.

Comment: @AlexVergara The members for the type now make sense, but the hard part is implementing all the member functions correctly. If you don't have specific requirements that `std::vector` cannot satisfy, then simply use `std::vector`. For example if you naively use `new[]` and `delete[]` your class template will either have horrible time complexity or will not be usable with non-default-constructible types. You will also likely not replicate the exception-safety guarantees of `std::vector` correctly.

Comment: A array allocated created with `new[]` will result in all members being initialized. `std::sting* const ss = new std::string[2]; ss[0] = "a"; ss[1] = "b";` results in 2 default constructor calls and 2 assignment operator calls for `std::string`. Compare this with `std::vector<std::string> ss; ss.reserve(2); ss.emplace_back("a"); ss.emplace_back("b");` where there are only 2 constructor calls. This can get expensive, if the default constructor does some expensive operations. Furthermore the way memory is allocated can be replaced by using a non-standard allocator for the vector.

Comment: @user17732522 that's just a base declaration for entering in the room. I am now reworking the library code to just have an `Array` a mimic of `std::Array` and a `Vector`, a mimic of the `std::vector`.  I was just thinking about the `new[]` and `delete[]` operators... But thanks for all the good points you give in the comments. I am coding from scratch for learning purposes, not any in particular further that design libraries based on `C++20` modules.

Comment: @fabian that's a really nice point. But, where's the second constructor call on the `reserve-emplace_back` operation for `std::vector`? Does not `emplace_back` constructs the literal directly in the vector making perfect fowarding? Even tho, it will still be two constructor calls for `std::string`? What I missed?

Comment: `reserve` just ensures a certain minimum capacity (no constructor calls, since the vector is empty before). `emplace_back` uses placement new or similar and there is only one constructor call per `emplace_back` call. There's a simplified collection implementation I've posted here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73071309/2991525 Basically the c string literal gets passed directly to the `std::string` constructor and the constructor initializes the new string object in a memory location where no string object has been constructed yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First there is a *mindset* (usually controversial) between the usage of the modern tools that the standard provides and the legacy ones.

You usually must be studing and asking things about `C++` modern features, not comparing them with the old ones. But, for learning purposes, I have to admit that it's quite interesting dive deep somethimes in this topics.

With that in mind, `std::vector` is a collection that makes much more that just care about the bytes stored in it. There is a constraint really important, that the data `must lie in contiguous memory`, and `std::vector` ensures this in its internal implementation. Also, has an already well known, well tested implementation of the `RAII` pattern, with the correct usage of `new[]` and `delete[]` operators. You can `reserve` storage and `emplace_abck()` elements in a convenient and performant way which makes this collection really unique... there are really a lot of reasons that shows why `std::vector` is really different from a dynamically allocated array.

Not only is to worry about manual memory management, which almost an undesirable thing to do in modern C++ (embedded systems, or operating system themselves are a good point to discuse this last sentence). It's about to have a tool, `std::vector<T>` that makes your life as developer easier, specially in a prone-error language like `C++`.

Note: I say `error-prone` because it's a really hard to master language, which needs a lot of study and training. You can make almost everything in the world, and has an incredible amount of features that aren't begginer friendly. Also, the retrocompatibility constraint makes it really bigger, with literally thousand of things that you must care about. So, with a great power, always comes a great responsability.